# Sending a model containing files from an MVC site to a Web Api site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.Net MVC site that allows the user to subtmit a form along with uploading files.

This part works. But in my MVC Post method, I need to call an ASP.Net Web API method and pass it the model.

This is the part I don't know how to do.

Here is my model in my MVC App:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }   
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC site I have the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    // the rest of the method
}
```

In this method the files and model are correctly populated. When I put a breakpoint and navigate over the Files property I can see the correct number of files with the correct names and file types.

In my Details method, I want to call a method on another site which is a Web API site.

Here is the method on the Web API site:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Foo(MyModel myModel)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Normally in my MVC method I would call the Web API using the `HttpClient` class using the `PostAsJsonAsync` method.

But when I do:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(urlServiceCall, myModel);
```

I receive this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
>
> Additional information: Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on
>   'System.Web.HttpInputStream'.

Comment: That is because it is trying to serialize the input stream of the files. I would suggest creating a new model for the web api that have the stream as byte arrays. the serializer would do better with the arrays than the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it is trying to serialize the input stream of the files. I would suggest creating a new model for the web api that have the stream as byte arrays.

```
public class PostedFile {
    public int ContentLength { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class WebApiModel {
    public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public List<PostedFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

the serializer would do better with the arrays than the stream.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up suing Nkosi's suggestion.

I created a new model for the Web Api:

```
public class OtherModel
{
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public List<byte[]> FileData { get; set; }
}
```

In my MVC method I used the following the Read the HttpPostFiles:

```
foreach (var file in model.Files)
{
    byte[] fileData = new byte[file.ContentLength];                
    await file.InputStream.ReadAsync(fileData, 0, file.ContentLength);
    testModel.FileData.Add(fileData);
}
```

Now I can use the HttpClient using `PostAsJsonAsync` and everything works correctly.