# How to add picture using HttpPostedFileBase from MVC to Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Web API in my project but I have a problem when I try add a picture to employee, all data register OK, only picture get an error.
In other projects work fine, but using Web API I can't add this.

Error:

> JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on
>   'System.Web.HttpInputStream'.

My model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Adress { get; set; }

    public int OcupationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    public virtual Occupation Occupation { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Pic { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrEdit(EmployeeViewModel employee)
    {

        if (employee.Id == 0)
        {

            if (employee.Pic != null)
            {
                var pic = Ultilidades.UploadPhoto(employee.Pic);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pic))
                {
                    employee.Picture = string.Format("~/Content/Pictures/{0}", pic);
                }
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Employee",employee).Result;
            TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "sucess!";
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred because `PostAsJsonAsync` method tries to serialize `HttpInputStream` object as string instead of byte array (note that JSON serializer works better with arrays rather than stream). You can create another model class specially designed for Web API which contains duplicated `int` & `string` properties from MVC viewmodel with additional byte array property to store `HttpPostedFileBase` object like this:

```
public class EmployeeWebApiModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public string Picture { get; set; }

    // byte array to hold HttpPostedFileBase content in Web API context
    public byte[] PicData { get; set; } 
}
```

Using Web API model class defined above, then read `HttpPostedFileBase` object and store it inside byte array property [using `BinaryReader`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030034/asp-net-mvc-read-file-from-httppostedfilebase-without-save), assuming you're already declared the model with `new` keyword:

```
var apiModel = new EmployeeWebApiModel();

// other logic here

var br = new BinaryReader(employee.Pic.InputStream);
apiModel.PicData = br.ReadBytes(employee.Pic.ContentLength);
```

Then, you can serialize Web API model class with `PostAsJsonAsync`:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Employee", apiModel).Result;
```

A similar issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285495/sending-a-model-containing-files-from-an-mvc-site-to-a-web-api-site) (with `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` instead of single `HttpPostedFileBase`).